# Accidental pip freeze outside of virtual env

Tags: python, pip, freeze

so this is embarrassing but I'm going to ask it.

I accidentally did a pip freeze > requirements.txt command outside of my virtual environment. It has made a requirements.txt file somewhere that I now can not find.

I am making the guess it is not good.

Any ideas

- where this file was likely made? I'm on OSX 10.8.5 and running 2.7.5
- how to get rid of it?

Thanks.

Comment: It should have went to whatever folder you were inside of in terminal when you ran the command.

Comment: pip freeze > requirements.txt is what I did. Sorry, should have been clearer. 

It did not go into the folder I was in when I did it. Hence my worry.

Comment: Unless you gave it a path, i don't think it can go anywhere else. Spotlight or `find` in terminal will find it if it really exists.

Comment: I didn't think so either re: path, but, its not there, and find can not find it. Someone suggested `sudo find` but that also came up empty.

Comment: A decent way to find the file would be to use `mdfind -name requirements.txt`, then looking through the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're on OS X, you can use the `mdfind` command – which queries the Spotlight database — to find the file:

```
$ mdfind -name requirements.txt
```

In theory it's possible to filter those results by the time they were created, but it's likely simplest to chain that to `xargs` to get the mtimes:

```
$ mdfind -0 -name requirements.txt | xargs -0 ls -alht
```

This will give you a list of all the `requirements.txt` files on your system, sorted by the time they were last modified.